# Rewriting double integral in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

Consider the double integral $$\mathrm{\int\limits_{\sqrt{2}}^2\int\limits_{\sqrt{4-y^2}}^2dxdy}$$

I can evaluate this integral directly and I found answer as $5-2\sqrt{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

However, I want to rewrite this integral in polar coordinates. Could you please help me in rewriting this integral in polar coordinates? Because this the main point I am stuck in.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. Show us what you've tried before asking for help!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) }^{\pi/4 }\int_{\sqrt{2}sec \theta }^{2csc \theta }rdrd\theta+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_{2}^{2csc \theta }rdrd\theta  $$
[image]